# Most efficient way to generate a really long string (tens of megabytes) in JS

Tags: javascript

I find myself needing to synthesize a ridiculously long string (like, tens of megabytes long) in JavaScript.  (This is to slow down a CSS selector-matching operation to the point where it takes a measurable amount of time.)

The best way I've found to do this is

```
var really_long_string = (new Array(10*1024*1024)).join("x");
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way - one that doesn't involve creating a tens-of-megabytes array first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The previously accepted version uses `String.prototype.concat()` which is [vastly slower](http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join) than using the optimized string concatenating operator, `+`. MDN also [recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) to keep away from using it in speed critical code.

I have made [three versions](http://jsperf.com/building-big-strings) of the above code to show the speed differences in a JsPerf. Converting it to using only using `concat` is only a third as fast as only using the string concatenating operator (Chrome - your mileage will vary). The edited version below will run twice as fast in Chrome

```js
var x = '1234567890'
var iterations = 14
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  x += x + x
}
```

Answer (score 72):

For ES6:

```
'x'.repeat(10*1024*1024)
```

Comment: very nice to see ES6 answers.  Feels like it is not your father Javascript anymore

Comment: Note: I'm not changing the accepted answer to this one because, at the time I asked the question, ES6 didn't even exist, so this would not have been an option.  A nice demonstration of why it's a Good Thing that accepted answers are no longer pinned to the top.

Answer (score 4):

This is the more efficient algorithm for generating very long strings in javascript:

```
function stringRepeat(str, num) {
    num = Number(num);

    var result = '';
    while (true) {
        if (num & 1) { // (1)
            result += str;
        }
        num >>>= 1; // (2)
        if (num <= 0) break;
        str += str;
    }

    return result;
}
```

more info here: http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/efficient-string-repeat.html.

Alternatively, in ECMA6 you can use [String.prototype.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method.

Answer (score 3):

Simply accumulating is vastly faster in Safari 5:

```
var x = "1234567890";
var iterations = 14;
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  x += x.concat(x);
}
alert(x.length); // 47829690
```

Essentially, you'll get `x.length * 3^iterations` characters.

Comment: I did manage to kill a Chrome content process with the original construct

Comment: Your approach is also vastly faster with Firefox.  I plotted it; they both take time proportional to the length of the string, but the Array technique becomes unacceptably slow at 2^20 bytes (one megabyte, not quite enough) where the concatenation technique is still tolerable out to 2^26 or so (64 megabytes, way more than I need).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a great implementation, but here's a general function based on @oligofren's solution:

```
function repeat(ch, len) {
  var result = ch;
  var halfLength = len / 2;
  while (result.length < len) {
    if (result.length <= halfLength) {
      result += result;
    } else {
      return result + repeat(ch, len - result.length);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

This assumes that concatenating a large string is faster than a series of small strings.